# Which Divs should be nested and which shouldn't?

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with some HTML/CSS lately and I've noticed I'm very sloppy with my divs, and I would like my code to be a lot more clean and reusable. So I'm starting off a new project, and I've already come across one of my biggest issues, here is what my code looks like:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="jumbotron-header">
        <h1>Header name</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

.jumbotron {
  width: 350px;
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #5a5955;
  opacity: .3;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.jumbotron-header {
  color: white;
}
```

So, it's only logical to think the jumbotrons header should be within the jumbotrons div tag, right? That way it is nested right inside of the jumbotron. Except now all of the text inside of the header is effected by the opacity of the jumbotron, so to "fix" this I would then move the header tag outside of the jumbotron tag, like this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron-header">
      <h1>Header name</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what makes my code so sloppy, it's like walking on a mine-field, once I get deep into a project I'm afraid to even touch the HTML. So I'm just wondering what is proper and what I should be doing?

Comment: container is not required and secondly use `header` tag for header purposes

Comment: well better you use html5 tag. you can use http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp to learn

Comment: Your original HTML is correct. The issue is that you are using `opacity` to (I assume) make the background translucent. Instead, you should use `background-color: rgba(xx, xx, xx, .3);` where the `xx`s are whatever the Red, Green, and Blue values translate into from hexadecimal

Comment: If you don't want jumbotron-header opacity be affected by jumbotron css then set jumbotron-headers opacity to a different setting and declare it !important.

Comment: @ed-ta woah.... no need for `!important`. Just using a more specific selector is enough (and *not* frowned upon).

Comment: @Jon, I know it was my second part of my comment and when I was trying to edit it said I was editing too fast so I couldnt edit. I was showing bad and good ways of going it.

Comment: This is off-topic due to being unclear what you are really asking, and too broad, and primarily opinion-based. Might be on-topic at CodeReview.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela This seems to be example code which is off-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original HTML is perfectly fine. In fact, changing the structure to anything else would make it *less* semantic and harder to use. The issue you are having with `opacity` is that it affects every color property of the element it is applied to, not just one of them.

It looks like you are trying to use `opacity` to make the background translucent (see-through, but not clear). Instead, you should use the `rgba(<red>, <green>, <blue>, <alpha>)` function to set the background color as translucent. Here, `<alpha>` is the value you were using for `opacity`.

```
.jumbotron {
  ...
  /* rgba() only takes decimal values. Your color of #5a5955 is equivalent
     to (90, 89, 85) in decimal. */
  background-color: rgba(90, 89, 85, 0.3);
  ...
}
```

This should maintain the opacity of `.jumbotron-header` and everything else inside of `.jumbotron`.

Remember that HTML is used to define the *structure* of your page, and CSS is used to define the *style* of it. These are separate things, and you should never *have* to change one to make the other work.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is keep your divs nested without the impact of opacity, then you can use rgba for the background color.

`background-color: rgba(90,89,85,0.3);`
A simple conversion of the # color value to rgb and presto!

Use this in place of your current background color and remove the opacity option.